# how can I add a unique restriction on a column with json data for a specific key

Tags: json, unique-constraint, mariadb-10.4

I have this database table

```
create table db_etennisnlive.bss_custom_option_template
(
    template_id           int unsigned auto_increment comment 'Template ID'
        primary key,
    title                 varchar(255)                                  null comment 'Title',
    is_active             smallint unsigned default 0                   not null comment 'Active',
    description           text                                          null comment 'Description',
    product_ids           longtext                                      null comment 'Product Ids',
    skus                  text                                          null comment 'Skus',
    created_at            timestamp         default current_timestamp() not null comment 'Creation Time',
    updated_at            timestamp         default current_timestamp() not null on update current_timestamp() comment 'Update Time',
    conditions_serialized mediumtext                                    null comment 'Condition assign product',
    options_data          mediumtext                                    null comment 'save option Data',
    apply_to              int unsigned                                  null comment 'number of product assign'
)
    comment 'Bss Custom Option Template';

create index BSS_CUSTOM_OPTION_TEMPLATE_TEMPLATE_ID
    on db_etennisnlive.bss_custom_option_template (template_id);
```

And on the column options_data there is a json string like this

```
{
  "1": {
    "is_delete": "",
    "previous_type": "drop_down",
    "previous_group": "select",
    "id": "1",
    "option_id": "1",
    "sort_order": "0",
    "title": "String",
    "type": "drop_down",
    "is_require": "1",
    "dependent_id": "1617179610350",
    "sku_option": "string_drop",
    "visibility": {
      "customer_group": "0,1,4,5,7,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21",
      "stores": "5,1,4,6,7,8,9,10"
    },
    "title_option": "{\"5\":\"Επιλογή χορδής\"}",
    "values": {
      "1": {
        "sort_order": "0",
        "dependent_id": "1617342342654",
        "option_type_id": "1",
        "is_delete": "",
        "title": "Unstrung",
        "price": 0,
        "price_type": "fixed",
        "sku": "UNSTRUNG",
        "depend_value": "",
        "title_option": "{\"5\":\"Άπλεκτη\"}",
        "option_price": "",
        "template_option_type_id": "1"
      },
      "410": {
        "sort_order": "1",
        "dependent_id": "1617618909687",
        "option_type_id": "410",
        "is_delete": "",
        "title": "Factory String",
        "price": 5,
        "price_type": "fixed",
        "sku": "FACTORY",
        "depend_value": "1617179610382",
        "title_option": "{\"5\":\"Εργοστασιακό πλέγμα\"}",
        "option_price": "{\"5\":\"25\"}",
        "template_option_type_id": "410"
      },
```

full json here

https://ots.ioweb.gr/?3ae8cb95ecf3bafc#yZUp8RAwa8q6wEyNaXATYKzf26dCwdK4ybLPgAUNbgs

I would like to enforce a database level restriction so that inside options_data column, and inside the key "1".values.*.sku the values of sku must be unique.

So for example I can't insert under 1.values.* two elements with the same SKU.

I'm not sure how this can be achieved.

Any ideas?

I'm on MariaDb 10.4